# Set Focus to Eclipse Console View in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I want to programatically set the focus to the Console View (that is bring that view to being active/displayed in case it isn't). How would I even get a reference to the ConsoleView so that I an call set focus to it from another plugin?

Comment: Do u mean the Eclipse default Console view or user defined console view?

Comment: Both. I need to bring the Default Eclipse Console View to the screen, just as is done in the standard out/in console when running a launch configuration.

Comment: Did this code work:`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewID)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment it is done like this:

```
String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
IViewPart consoleView = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                                  .getActivePage().showView(id);
```

To display a specific (custom) console page:

```
MessageConsole customConsole = ...;
((IConsoleView) consoleView).display(customConsole);
```

Taken from [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F) where futher the custom console creation can be found.